# Simple merge two binary trees question JS

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am wondering why this solution works on LeetCode as when I logged the output of the function in my console it appears an array of nonsense to me: [ 1, 3, 2, 5, val: NaN, left: undefined, right: undefined ] which is different to the output shown on LeetCode.

I am quite new to programming, thank you so much for your help!

question:
[LeetCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVcF7.png)

code I dont understand:

```
 const mergeTrees = (t1, t2) => {
     
    if (!t1) {
        return t2;
    }
    if (!t2) {
        return t1;
    }
    t1.val += t2.val;
    t1.left = mergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left);
    t1.right = mergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right);

    return t1;
  
};

console.log(mergeTrees([1,3,2,5],
        [2,1,3,null,4,null,7]))
```

leetcode output:`[3,4,5,5,4,null,7]`

my console.log output: `[ 1, 3, 2, 5, val: NaN, left: undefined, right: undefined ]`

Comment: Could you post the code here?

Comment: you are right. makes no sens

Comment: where did you find this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

this makes a lot more sens to me
can you try it ?

if you consider t1 and t2 as lines, and you stack them, you can simply add values column by column. and keeping nulls.

```
var t1 = [1, 3, 2, 5]
var t2 = [2, 1, 3, null, 4, null, 7]

var i = 0;
var t = [];
while (typeof t1[i] !== 'undefined' || typeof t2[i] !== 'undefined') {
    // keeps nulls and undefined
    if ((t1[i] === null || typeof t1[i] === 'undefined') && (t2[i] === null || typeof t2[i] === 'undefined'))
        t[i] = null;
    // just add values
    else
        t[i] = (t1[i]||0) + (t2[i]||0);
    // got to next step
    i++;
}

console.log(t)
// [3, 4, 5, 5, 4, null, 7]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and it looks great to me! but im just mainly curious why that code works on leetcode but logs strangely :(

Comment: Then Write to the website creator. It's just a plain bug for me.